# XML signature with x509 sha256 fail

Tags: c#, xml, x509, sha256

I want "xml signature with x509 sha256 " BUT this code only give signature (byte[]) ı want signature xmldocument with this x509 please help me

```
XmlDocument docc = new XmlDocument();
docc.Load("C:\\Users\\bera\\Desktop\\Sertifika\\aa.xml");

X509Store storeMyCurrentUser = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
storeMyCurrentUser.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

X509Certificate2 certRCA = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\bera\\Desktop\\RCA.p12", "0123456789");
if (!storeMyCurrentUser.Certificates.Contains(certRCA))
     storeMyCurrentUser.Add(certRCA);
 RSACryptoServiceProvider _provider = null;
 //doc.OuterXml
 byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml);
 if (certRCA.HasPrivateKey)
 {
     _provider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certRCA.PrivateKey;
     byte[] sigedBytes = _provider.SignData(data, "SHA256");
     string a= System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sigedBytes);
     Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: Have you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?

Comment: yes , but I must do x509 and I ready Personal Information Exchange (.pfx) in x509 with sha256 but It signed with <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" ???why

Comment: Well you haven't shown your attempt to use the *normal* XML signing APIs, so it's hard to tell what you've done wrong...